# How to increase the number of events remembered in Undo/Redo history in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

How to increase the number of events remembered in Undo/Redo history in Android Studio?
I am used to Eclipse remembering a huge quantity of steps, and I could usually revert back to since when I started working on a file, even if it was hundreds edits ago, but Android Studio remembers a fairly small amount of steps to go back to.

Comment: Too bad there is no other good tag to get more people involved in this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Accordingly to [this thread](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-21306) you can try to change `Registry | undo.documentUndoLimit` value, but this may cause future troubles, at least with memory overflow (*stackowerflow* :) ). To edit it:

1. Press Ctrl+Shift+A, type *Registry* 
   [image]
2. find `undo.documentUndoLimit` item and set value you wish (default is 100)
   [image]